# How to save Checkbox Value and status

Tags: javascript

I need to save values as well as status of the checkboxes on my page; so I can check at the time of submit if the checked box has been unchecked and use its value using comparestatus() function for further logic. I have tried this and I get error that variable periodCHK is not defined.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Periods" value="25301601" >
<input type="checkbox" name="Periods" value="25301602"  checked>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $j(document).ready( function() {
        var periodCHK;
        $j(":checkbox").each( function() {                          
            periodCHK["$j(this.id).val()"]=($j(this).is(':checked'));
        } );

        console.log(periodCHK);

        function comparestatus() {
            var periodstring; 
            if (!$j(this).is(':checked')) {
                // if this one was checked before, grab it and make a string
                if (window.periodCHK["$j(this.id).val()"]) 
                {
                    periodstring+=["$j(this.id).val()"] + ",";
                }
            }
        }
    } );
</script>
```

Comment: You must define periodCHK as Object, `var periodCHK = {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `periodCHK` variable was (correctly) declared using a var inside your document.ready module, so it only exists inside that function scope. You can access it simply through:

`if (periodCHK["$j(this.id).val()"])`

(Note: in order to have your variable be accessible in the global scope (`window`) you would either have to declare it without a `var` or explicitly assign it to the window. However, this is generally bad practice.)

Answer (score 1):

You declare `var periodCHK` inside a function, so it doesn't become a property of `window`. Where you call it with `window.periodCHK` inside `comparestatus`, it should just be `periodCHK`. That should work, because the function `comparestatus` is declared in the same function where `periodCHK` is also declared. They are in the same scope.